# Configure Windows 10 WAMP PHP to connect to SQLServer 2008

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, windows-10

I have been spending days on this project trying to connect to a database and have reached some what of a stand still. I'm hoping someone has some experience with this.

I have been given Remote Desktop credentials to a Windows Server(R) 2008 box. There is a database running on that machine, and the client would like to pull data out of it from another domain - it is running SQLServer 2008.

As a test I am trying to connect to it via a local WAMP install. I was able to get the following .dll's running in my local PHP after downgrading it to its 32 bit version:
- php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
- php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll

However, when I try to use PDO or the sqlsrv_connect function to connect, I receive the error message:

```
SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712
```

When I try to download and install the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434) - I receive the following error message:

```
Installation of this product failed because it is not supported on this operating system. For information on supported configurations, see the product documentation.
```

My question is, is there a way to connect to a SQLServer 2008 database from a WAMP install on a Windows 10 machine? - as far as I can tell it is not supported on Windows 10.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Windows 10 is not good for development. `.htaccess` is out of control.

Comment: It's been a while since I dug into PHP but assuming things haven't changed much in the last few years you're going to run into issues with binary versions.  You say you got it working with 32bit of the PDO driver what is your runtime compiler?  It might be the Visual Studio having the issue.

Comment: @whoisearth - not really working - just "find-able" by php - meaning when I run the phpinfo() function those extensions are now listed. Alternatively, there was nothing I could do with the 64 bit version of php to get those extensions to show up on my machine. It looks like I do have a version Visual Studio on this computer but it looks like the issue I am running into is that I cannot install the required driver for those functions on Windows 10.

Comment: I know it doesn't answer the question - but we ended up abandoning the Windows 10 WAMP environment and went with actual IIS hosting and can now connect to the database no problem (using PHP even), I was able to test the connection from our Windows 10 machine by downloading Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I had hoped that would install any potential dependencies for PHP to be able to connect too... but it did not. Anyway - just an update and thanks for the comments - if anyone can successfully connect to SQLServer 2008 from Windows 10 and write about it, I'm sure it would help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Windows 10. I have the 64bit wamp server installed running php 7.0.10.

I was able to connect to a Microsoft Azure database.

I had to install The 
Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server® - Windows
this version of it

```
ENU\x64\msodbcsql.msi
```

This is the url:
    https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434

I also had to load "php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll" file to the folder 
    C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/ext

and add the

```
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
```

to the php.ini file

this was for a Cakephp 3.55 project